# How do I get the top 1 of a linked table?

Tags: sql, t-sql

Ok, so say I have two tables.

Question

- questionID
- QuestionDescription

Answer

- AnswerID
- QuestionID
- AnswerDescription
- CreatedDate

And say I want to create a query which returns the question and latest created answer like these columns

QuestionID QuestionName AnswerDescription CreatedDate

Is that possible?

I can do a query that gets all the combinations of quesitons and answers

```
SELECT q.QuestionID, q.QuestionName, a.AnswerDescription, a.CreatedDate FROM QUESTION q
INNER JOIN ANSWER a
ON q.questionID = a.QuestionID
```

but is there a way I can do something like this but have it only return the latest answer instead of all of them?

Comment: do you want only the latest answer or the latest answer to for each question?

Comment: latest answer for each question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get per question, SQL Server 2005+

```
SELECT
   q.QuestionID, q.QuestionName,
   a.AnswerDescription, a.CreatedDate
FROM
    QUESTION q
    CROSS APPLY
    (
     SELECT TOP 1 a2.AnswerDescription, a2.CreatedDate
     FROM ANSWER a2
     WHERE q.questionID = a2.QuestionID
     ORDER BY a2.CreatedDate DESC
    ) a
```

Comment: fantastic! thanks, i never knew about the Cross Apply function in SQL. I will have to do some research to understand what it is. Am I right to assume that instead of referencing another table, you are defining one inside the cross apply?

Comment: yes. It allows a set solution to something that would be "row by row" in older versions. And it's simpler than aggregate solutions (eg from Mikael Eriksson's otherwise valid answer)

Comment: I've been trying to get my head round cross apply for a while. I've taken this and Mikael's answer below, adapted for my schema, and profiled them. Interestingly, Mikael's is faster with less reads -- typical example being 7500 reads/39ms for Cross Apply vs 100 reads/13ms for Inner Join. Now obviously your mileage will vary depending on what your schema is and how much data you've got, so it's worth trying both approaches, looking at the results in SQL Profiler and see how they compare for you (it's entirely possible you'll see the opposite to me -- this is just a heads-up after all :-) ).

Comment: @Chris J: ROW_NUMBER is better in SQL Server 2008 so quite possible Mikael's answer works better.

Comment: I tried out both, and the RowNumber solution was instant whilst the Cross Apply took about 7 or 8 secs to display. Like ChrisF though, I agree, this is just for my system, it may yield a different result in other situations.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT q.QuestionID, 
       q.QuestionName, 
       a.AnswerDescription, 
       a.CreatedDate
FROM QUESTION AS q
  INNER JOIN (SELECT QuestionID,
                     AnswerDescription,
                     CreatedDate,
                     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY QuestionID 
                                       ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC) AS rn
              FROM ANSWER) AS a       
    ON q.questionID = a.QuestionID AND 
       a.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT top 1 q.QuestionID, q.QuestionName, a.AnswerDescription, a.CreatedDate FROM QUESTION q
INNER JOIN ANSWER a
ON q.questionID = a.QuestionID
ORDER BY a.CreatedDate DESC
```